# Python Telnet if read = xxxx

Tags: python, telnet

I'm having a small issue in Python with Telnet. im trying to have the script start up by determining whether the telnet connection is already logged in or not. My code looks something like the following:

```
if TLNT.read_until("login: ",2): #if it reads the login prompt:
    login(USER,PASS) #runs the function used to login to the system
main() #otherwise will determine system is already logged in and start the main script
```

The Issue here I am unsure of the formatting here, as the script will skip over the login function even though i have purposely logged out the telnet system so i know that it sees the login prompt. if the telnet prompt is left at "login: " what will read_until return?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i just updated the question to provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation!](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until)

> Telnet.read_until(expected[, timeout])
>
> Read until a given string, expected, is encountered or until timeout seconds have passed.
>
> When no match is found, return whatever is available instead, possibly the empty string. Raise EOFError if the connection is closed and no cooked data is available.

It does not return `True` or `False`, so you probably don't want to use the return value as your conditional expression.

Comment: Does `read_until`'s return include the argument string? Maybe he could test for `if 'login:' in TLNT.read_until('login:', 2): login(USER, PASS)`. I don't have a telnet server to test on and don't have time to follow the function calls in the source (it eventually returns `self.cookedq` but I don't know how that's populated)

Comment: Yes, it includes the matched text. 
>>> tn = telnetlib.Telnet('...')
>>> tn.read_until("login:", 2)
'\r\n\r\nSunOS 5.8\r\n\r\r\n\rlogin:'
  That allows reading whatever the output is until a prompt is encountered, then processing the output.